# Convert Vulkan MemoryPropertyFlags to MemoryPropertyFlagBits

Tags: c++, vulkan

In the Vulkan c++ API, `physical_device.getMemoryProperties().memoryTypes` returns an instance of `MemoryPropertyFlags`, aka `Flags<MemoryPropertyFlagBits>`.
I'd like to simply recover the bit mask to easily match it with `MemoryPropertyFlagBits` for buffer creation requests.

I realize it is a simple question but for some reason I am unable to find any information on Flags and navigating though the headers leads me nowhere. All I know from clang completion is that Flags has a few binary operators.

Comment: reinterpret_cast. Why would you want to mix the types though? Flags are flags, and bit is a bit.

Comment: @krOoze Why a `reinterpret_cast`? There's an explicit cast operator to the underlying mask type in `Flags<>`, it seems that `static_cast` would make more sense and be less error prone.

Comment: @vandench There is cast operator to `VkMemoryPropertyFlags` but not to `MemoryPropertyFlagBits`. Not sure, but might need two nested `static_cast`s which is decisively ugly; then again it could be wrapped inside some utility function. Then again again, it does not seem semantically correct since flags might have multiple bits, while bits only one, so `reinterpret_cast` seems appropriate semantically given this danger. Anyway, I am still not clear what is the OP's engoal here. `MemoryPropertyFlags` was already designed such that it can do all the necessary things one might want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vulkan.hpp the Flags class is defined as

```cpp
template <typename BitType>
class Flags
{
public:
    using MaskType = typename std::underlying_type<BitType>::type;

    // constructors
    constexpr Flags() noexcept : m_mask( 0 ) {}

    constexpr Flags( BitType bit ) noexcept : m_mask( static_cast<MaskType>( bit ) ) {}

    constexpr Flags( Flags<BitType> const & rhs ) noexcept = default;

    constexpr explicit Flags( MaskType flags ) noexcept : m_mask( flags ) {}

    // relational operators
#if defined( VULKAN_HPP_HAS_SPACESHIP_OPERATOR )
    auto operator<=>( Flags<BitType> const & ) const = default;
#else
    constexpr bool operator<( Flags<BitType> const & rhs ) const noexcept
    {
        return m_mask < rhs.m_mask;
    }

    constexpr bool operator<=( Flags<BitType> const & rhs ) const noexcept
    {
        return m_mask <= rhs.m_mask;
    }

    constexpr bool operator>( Flags<BitType> const & rhs ) const noexcept
    {
        return m_mask > rhs.m_mask;
    }

    constexpr bool operator>=( Flags<BitType> const & rhs ) const noexcept
    {
        return m_mask >= rhs.m_mask;
    }

    constexpr bool operator==( Flags<BitType> const & rhs ) const noexcept
    {
        return m_mask == rhs.m_mask;
    }

    constexpr bool operator!=( Flags<BitType> const & rhs ) const noexcept
    {
        return m_mask != rhs.m_mask;
    }
#endif

    // logical operator
    constexpr bool operator!() const noexcept
    {
        return !m_mask;
    }

    // bitwise operators
    constexpr Flags<BitType> operator&( Flags<BitType> const & rhs ) const noexcept
    {
        return Flags<BitType>( m_mask & rhs.m_mask );
    }

    constexpr Flags<BitType> operator|( Flags<BitType> const & rhs ) const noexcept
    {
        return Flags<BitType>( m_mask | rhs.m_mask );
    }

    constexpr Flags<BitType> operator^( Flags<BitType> const & rhs ) const noexcept
    {
        return Flags<BitType>( m_mask ^ rhs.m_mask );
    }

    constexpr Flags<BitType> operator~() const noexcept
    {
        return Flags<BitType>( m_mask ^ FlagTraits<BitType>::allFlags.m_mask );
    }

    // assignment operators
    constexpr Flags<BitType> & operator=( Flags<BitType> const & rhs ) noexcept = default;

    constexpr Flags<BitType> & operator|=( Flags<BitType> const & rhs ) noexcept
    {
        m_mask |= rhs.m_mask;
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr Flags<BitType> & operator&=( Flags<BitType> const & rhs ) noexcept
    {
        m_mask &= rhs.m_mask;
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr Flags<BitType> & operator^=( Flags<BitType> const & rhs ) noexcept
    {
        m_mask ^= rhs.m_mask;
        return *this;
    }

    // cast operators
    explicit constexpr operator bool() const noexcept
    {
        return !!m_mask;
    }

    explicit constexpr operator MaskType() const noexcept
    {
        return m_mask;
    }

#if defined( VULKAN_HPP_FLAGS_MASK_TYPE_AS_PUBLIC )
public:
#else
private:
#endif
    MaskType m_mask;
};
```

The Flags class can be constructed by passing in the bit type, or the underlying type (`VkMemoryPropertyFlagBits` is an enum, and the underlying type is probably going to be something like an `int`). There is an explicit operator to get out the underlying value, which can be accessed by static casting the Flags class to the underlying type. You can also declare `VULKAN_HPP_FLAGS_MASK_TYPE_AS_PUBLIC` in your compile flags and access the mask directly. There are of course also all necessary operators defined to interact with the Flags class as if it were a raw integer.

Given `VkFlags` is a `uint32_t` I'm not sure why they don't offer an implicit or explicit cast to `VkFlags`.

The safest way would probably be

```cpp
vk::Flags<VkMemoryPropertyFlagBits> flags = VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT;
VkFlags vkFlags = static_cast<decltype(flags)::MaskType>(flags);
```

This will always cast it to the correct type (using the wrong type will produce a compile error), and the conversion between `MaskType` and `VkFlags` should be implicit.